Why does the nucleus not exist in mature red blood cells?
I'm currently a high schooler learning biology. I just wanted to know why does the nucleus not exist in mature red blood cells. It would be great if someone answered my question in a basic way as I have not learnt it in depth yet, just wanted to understand the basics first. Thanks in advance for your help. :)

Hi Iris, and welcome. Is there no explanation in your book? Did you do an internet search in an attempt to answer this? Evidence of research (e.g. a quote and a link) is required on this site. Do you want to know how enucleation occurs, or why? The "why" is that that's what evolved in mammals because it conferred some kind of advantage at some point (the "why" will be a teleological reason). Please read about it and ask a question about something specific that you don't understand with a quote from and a link to the source. Thanks.

This paper might help, especially the second paragraph of the introduction section.

worth noting this is only true of mammal red blood cells. avian red blood cells for instance have nuclei.

Well, a cell requires nucleus for growth, modification and maturation. Once the cell has attained its size and functionality, nucleus is not a necessity. As you know RBCs carry oxygen (also carbon dioxide in a different form, about 20 -25 percent), space is required for it. So, to increase the capacity of the RBCs to carry more oxygen, by increasing the space to accommodate more haemoglobin, nucleus is destroyed in an RBC. The avg. lifespan of an RBC is 120 days. so, for 120 days, it can function without the nucleus. You may think of other examples of cells that don't contain nucleus like Sieve cells of phloem etc.

You might benefit from reading the second paragraph of the introduction linked to in the comment below the question as well. You're answering with hypothesis, not accepted fact (though it is often presented as fact.) Why are mammals the exception to nucleated blood cells? Are avian RBCs less efficient than mammalian RBCs?

Hmm, evolution of birds and mammals is not along the same line. Also, camels and llamas have nucleus in their RBCs. The answer I provided may not be the fact, but the person requested a simplified answer do I tried to provide the answer simply. By the way, thanks for the paper. I shall definitely go through it.

You've missed the point entirely. Mammalian RBCs are no more efficient than avian RBCs, so your answer doesn't make any sense. Also, camel RBCs are enucleated. Don't trust the superficial sources of info on the internet

Would you please elaborate.

I don't believe in giving an entire ocean when one asks for a glass of water. For initial reference one should go through the most well accepted hypothesis even if it may be not completely true. You pointed that camel don't have nucleus but what about llamas? Same/similar selection pressures might have several possible outcomes and routes.

Clearly you're unaware that llamas also have RBC's without nuclei. Before you ask, so do alpacas, vicuñas, and guanacos. You've been wrong three times now. What has your observation about birds' evolution got to do with my comment about red blood cells? Your answer isn't an ocean, but it also isn't correct.

Ya, i acknowledge that my answer is wrong. I came to know that the dark structure of their RBCs in not nucleus but some sort of microtubules or something. But the conventional yet wrong answer is the answer given by me. Thank you.
